# How to make a full width, full height image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my header section, I have used bootstaps `col-md-6` on the left-hand side, but on the right I want an image which covers the full length and width of this section leaving no white space at all?

Thanks in advance!

Example image (right space is where I want the image):

[image]

Comment: have you tried percentage value ? width:100% and height:100% or auto

Comment: @wpcoder I've tried that, my issue is because code-md-6 isn't full width and height, the image can't be either if you get me?

Comment: try to force that through `!important` tag in css.

Comment: `100%` is 100% of the container iirc. Try `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`